# Is there a way to have MySQL GROUP BY utilize trailing whitespace?

Tags: mysql

I recently had an issue come up where I noticed that MySQL would ignore trailing whitespace when issuing a GROUP BY. Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `foo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And here's an example query I ran (not a production use, but shows what I'm trying to fix):

```
SELECT foo, CHAR_LENGTH(foo) FROM myTable
WHERE foo='bar'
GROUP BY foo
```

Which would return a result set:

```
| foo  | CHAR_LENGTH(foo)  |
+------+-------------------+
| Bar  |                 4 |
```

All well and good, except 'Bar' is length three, not four. So I went to examing the individual entries (No group by):

```
SELECT foo, CHAR_LENGTH(foo) FROM myTable
WHERE foo='bar'

| foo  | CHAR_LENGTH(foo)  |
+------+-------------------+
| Bar  |                 3 |
| Bar  |                 3 |
| Bar  |                 3 |
| Bar  |                 4 |
| Bar  |                 3 |
```

Now, there are five entries for Bar, four of which correctly report a length 3. But there's one that reports a length of four.

It turns out the one with length four has a space on the end: "Bar ". I would have expected `GROUP BY` to treat this as a completely different value and not lump it with the other "Bar"s.

Is there a way to tell MySQL to consider values different if they have trailing (or leading) whitespace?

(running mysql 5.1.55 64-bit on mac osx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`char` values are space-padded when they are stored, so all trailing whitespace is assumed to be padding and removed when retrieving values.  `varchar` fields will retain trailing whitespace, but by default it is removed for comparisons.  (see [`The CHAR and VARCHAR types`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html))

To retain the trailing whitespace for `varchar` values, use the [`binary`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) operator.  Something like `SELECT foo, CHAR_LENGTH(foo) FROM myTable
WHERE foo='bar'
GROUP BY BINARY foo` should do what you want.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. worked great

Comment: This points us in the right direction, but the query you provided doesn't work. Note that expression #1 in your SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column foo which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. If you add Binary to foo, then it would work but the results will not be in string form!

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` clause can be multiple fields and/or calculated fields:

```
SELECT foo, CHAR_LENGTH(foo) FROM myTable
WHERE foo='bar'
GROUP BY foo,CHAR_LENGTH(foo)
```